# File not found issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My requirement is to use linters in my base package from **Flutter stable** as well as from **pedantic** in analysis_options.yaml file and I will use the analysis_options.yaml file in my other packages which are dependent on my base package. But while referring both (in my base project) linters, in the Dart Analysis tab of android studio or PROBLEMS tab of visual studio code I didn't see any error. While using **flutter analyze** command, I'm facing the below issue.

[image: Img]

I have created a simple projects to replicate this issue which can be found below.

[MyProjects](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=62760496643005140605)

With the above attachment, I have two projects (Project1 and Project2). In my machine, while using flutter analyze command in both projects, the Project1 doesn't show any issues and Project2 will show the above error (file_not_found). The difference between those projects is, in Project1, I will have analysis_options.yaml file under **example folder** and in Project2 I won't have analysis_options.yaml file under **example folder**.

But while testing these two projects with different machines (I have tested around more than 10 machines) I'm facing below scenarios.

1. No issues with both project
2. File not found issues with two projects
3. No issue with Project1 and File not found issue only with Project2.

Since the issue is inconsistent with different machine, I can't resolve this.

I have tested this with Flutter stable channel and in the beta channel.

**Note:** If I remove the example folder I don't see any errors, but I need to have that example folder in my packages.

**Replication Steps:**

1. Extract the attachment
2. Move to the terminal from the projects and give flutter analyze command.

**Flutter installed info:**

[image: Info]